# asp.net mvc selectlist "{ }" appears in result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I'm working on an asp.net mvc project.

I've been able to combine 2 fields from a table into a drop down list.  However, in both the create and index views, I get these "{ }" brackets and I can't figure out how to get rid of them.

Controller:
//Get: /Create

```
var units = db.EquipmentLists
            .Where(s => s.Unit != null)
            .OrderBy(s => s.Unit)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Description = s.Unit + " - " + s.MakeModel
            }).ToList();

        ViewBag.Units = new SelectList(units);
```

//Post: /Create

```
ViewBag.Units = new SelectList(db.EquipmentLists.OrderBy(x => x.Unit + " - " + x.MakeModel));
```

Create.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Unit, (SelectList)ViewBag.Units, "Select one...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Don't know why I'm getting the `"{ }"` brackets in the views.  Just want to get rid of them.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is creating an anonymous object with a property named `Description`.

When you use the `SelectList` constructor with a single argument (where the parameter is `IEnumerable`) the method calls `.ToString()` on each item in the collection to generate the values and display text for each option), and is only suitable where the collection contains simple types (e.g. `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<int>`)

Change the constructor to specify the property of your object your want for the value and display text using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.) that accepts arguments for `dataValueField,` and `dataTextField`

```
ViewBag.Units = new SelectList(units, "Description", "Description");
```

Alternatively you can create a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` directly using

```
ViewBag.Units = db.EquipmentLists
    .Where(s => s.Unit != null)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Unit)
    .Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = s.Unit + " - " + s.MakeModel,
        Text = s.Unit + " - " + s.MakeModel,
    });
```

and adjust the view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Unit, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Units, "Select one...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the arguments for selectlist.  Really hit home.  New to MVC and it's difficult to understand the tips VS is spewing out when creating a constructor.

Comment: I would also suggest that you use a view model and get rid of your use of `ViewBag` ([What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)), and your view model will contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Units` - refer the code in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a typical example

Answer (score 0):

What Stephan said is correct, but let me explain it in a little detail.

```
ViewBag.[VAR] = new SelectList([list], [value], [text]);
```

uses the `SelectList` constructor detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

As long as you have a collection that inherits IEnumerable, it'll work with a select list. `dataValueField` refers to whatever you want the html `value` property to have, `dataTextField` refers to whatever you want it to display.

This is handy to use with a data table object as you could just concatenate fields as the text. For example:

```
public class Obj1
{
   public int id {get; set}
   public string field1 {get; set;}
   public string field2 {get; set;}
   public string DisplayField {get {return field1 + " " + field2;}}
}
//In your controller
public ActionResult Create()
{
   ...other code
   List<Obj1> list = GetAllObj1(); //however you get the fields
   ViewBag.Fields = new SelectList(list, "id", "DisplayField");
   return View();
} ...
```

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in Controller side 
ViewBag.Units = db.EquipmentLists.Select(s => new SelectListItem{ Value = s.Unit +" - " + s.MakeModel,Text = s.Unit + " - " + s.MakeModel});

and Use Below Line in View Side
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Unit, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Units,"Select one...", new { @class = "form-control" })